# conditions are met, but program not breaking out of while loop

Tags: python

The program isn't breaking out of the while loop even when either "exit" or `num` is inputted. At the bottom of the function, I tried checking with `guess == num`, and that returns true. The code outside of the function at the very bottom is the basic structure of this function and that one works properly. Would the problem for not breaking out of the while loop happen to have anything to do with the two for loops in the function? Thanks.

```
def cowsAndBulls():  
    guess = ''  
    num = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))

    while guess != num or guess != 'exit':    
        guess = input('Please enter a guess for a 4-digit number (\'exit\' to leave): ')
        numL = [digit for digit in num]
        guessL = [digit for digit in guess]
        cow = 0
        bull = 0

        for digit in guessL:
            if digit in numL and guessL.index(digit) == numL.index(digit):
                cow = cow + 1
                guessL[guessL.index(digit)] = 'G'
                numL[numL.index(digit)] = 'N'
        for digit in guessL: 
            if digit in numL and guessL.index(digit) != numL.index(digit):
                bull = bull + 1
                guessL[guessL.index(digit)] = 'G'
                numL[numL.index(digit)] = 'N'

        print(num)
        print('Number of cows: ' + str(cow))
        print('Number of bulls: ' + str(bull))
        print(guess == num) 

cowsAndBulls()




guess = ''
num = str(random.randint(0,5))
while guess != num:
    guess = input()
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't end is because unless both of them are false, the while loop is satisfied. This line here is where your troubles are from:

`while guess != num or guess != 'exit':`

If `guess == 'exit'`, this is what happens:

`while False or True:`

The loop will keep running because `False or True` returns `True`.
To fix this, I would use a single variable to keep the game running and make it false when you want to end the game.

`while running:`

Then inside the loop, if guess == 'exit' or num then set running to `False` and the program will end.

Comment: All good as beginner advice, but, I think the intro reasoning is twisting the mind, as  in the case of `guess == 'exit'` the condition to be evaluated is `while True or False`. With regard to the suggested _unified_ condition variable (`running`): In my experience mixing in break condition into the normal conditions is too implicit, why not use `break`inside the loop when `guess == 'exit'`? But as I wrote, all well to go further in learning python.

Comment: @Dilettant I see what you're getting at. I may be a little biased coming from game development. It is more useful to have `while variable:` loops because when you have nested loops you can easily control if you want to exit one or both of the loops and in which order.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def cowsAndBulls():  
    guess = ''  
    num = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))

    while guess != num and guess != 'exit':    
        guess = input('Please enter a guess for a 4-digit number (\'exit\' to leave): ')
        numL = [digit for digit in num]
        guessL = [digit for digit in guess]
        cow = 0
        bull = 0

        for digit in guessL:
            if digit in numL and guessL.index(digit) == numL.index(digit):
                cow = cow + 1
                guessL[guessL.index(digit)] = 'G'
                numL[numL.index(digit)] = 'N'
        for digit in guessL: 
            if digit in numL and guessL.index(digit) != numL.index(digit):
                bull = bull + 1
                guessL[guessL.index(digit)] = 'G'
                numL[numL.index(digit)] = 'N'

        print(num)
        print('Number of cows: ' + str(cow))
        print('Number of bulls: ' + str(bull))
        print(guess == num) 

cowsAndBulls()
```

Change your `or` to an `and`.

Answer (score -1):

I was playing around with your code and I found the error, Change your while loop from and **or** to an **and**

```
while guess != num or guess != 'exit':
```

to

```
while guess != num and guess != 'exit':
```

will make the loop stop once you type exit.

Good luck!